# How to stop VS code from automatically entering parameters into my callback function (stop inserting suggestions on a keypress)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code version `1.25.1`. This behaviour wasn't in any of the previous version and I'm not able to find the setting in `settings.json` to help me out. I couldn't find a post on this issue so I'm posting this.

[image: When I am entering a parameter]

When I press `,`

[image: When I press comma]

This behaviour is very irritating and unproductive and I was wondering how can I edit my `settings.json` to disable this.

**Edit**

Note: I am using default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

will remove the <kbd>,</kbd> as a completion (commit) character.  You can still use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the highlighted suggestion.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it fixed the issue :)